# The most efficient method for generating new prime numbers

Tags: number-theory, prime-numbers

What is the most efficient method for generating a prime number larger than the largest known prime number, and what is the complexity of this method?

Techniques considered:

- [Mills' Constant](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mills%27_constant) - cannot be used, since the exact value of this number is unknown
- [Rowland Recurrence Relation](https://sites.google.com/site/srihariramanathan/therowlandrecurrencerelation) - cannot be used, since it is not monotonously increasing

I know that the largest prime number record is usually broken when a [Mersenne Prime](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mersenne_prime) is found. This happens when a prime $N$ is found, such that $2^N-1$ is also prime. But I cannot see how to turn this into a method which would guarantee finding a larger prime number efficiently.

So the only algorithm that comes to mind is this:

- Set $P_1=2$
- Set $P_2=3$
- Run forever:

  - Set $P_3=$ the largest prime factor of $P_1P_2+1$
  - Set $P_1=P_1P_2$
  - Set $P_2=P_3$

But due to step of calculating the largest prime factor, this algorithm is not very efficient.

Thanks

Comment: This sequence is the (2nd) Euclid-Mullin sequence: https://oeis.org/A000946

Comment: @jp26: Thanks. First of all, thinking about it again, I'm not so sure that this sequence yields **only** prime numbers (in fact, I'm pretty sure that it doesn't). Second, even if it did, it would still require an extremely long computation in order to find the next number in this sequence.

Answer (score 6):

Most numbers are (relatively) hard to check for primality. In order to find a record prime you need to select some special form which is easy to check. Mersenne numbers are the easiest to check, so they're a natural choice. Proth primes (those of the form $k\cdot2^n+1$ with $2^n>k$) are almost as easy, as are generalized Fermat numbers $k^n+1$.

The method you suggest is not practical since it requires factorization which is vastly harder than primality testing. As a ballpark it takes a few seconds to check if a 250-digit number is prime, where it would take thousands of processor-years to factor a number of this size (worst case -- a prime for the former and a hard semiprime in the latter). All the computers presently on the planet couldn't factor a number as large as the record prime, not even if they had been running since the Big Bang.